# DjangoModelFactory JsonField returning Unicode data instead of dictionary data

Tags: django, django-testing, factory-boy, django-jsonfield

I am trying to set a field of type `JSONField` using factoryboy `DjangoModelFactory`. Here is the code:

```
class SubmittedAnswer(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(default={})
    is_rule_check_passed = models.NullBooleanField()

class SubmittedAnswerFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = SubmittedAnswer

    data = {"option_ids": [1]}
```

In database queryset response, I am getting the `data` field as `Unicode` and not as `dict`.

```
'data': u'{"option_ids":[3]}'}]
```

Am I missing out on something?

Comment: It's likely to be related to your ``JSONField`` implementation; which one are you using?

Comment: Hi @Xelnor, I am using django-jsonfield - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonfield

Answer (score 0):

My guess (based on the format of the output you gave) is that you perform a query using `values(...)`.

The `QuerySet` returned when using `values` returns items as dictionary instances (with each key corresponding to a requested column of the model) rather than Model instances (see [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values)). The values in the dictionary correspond to what is stored in the database, there is no complex object conversion from the data to the given field, as there is no instantiation of the model.

If you want to get model instances directly, use a regular `QuerySet`, eg.
`SubmittedAnswerFactory.objects.filter(...)`. And if you want to select only some fields when performing the actual SQL query for optimization, and still get model instances, use `only` (or `defer`) instead of `values` (see [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#only)).

See:

```
for a in SubmittedAnswer.objects.only('option_ids'):
    print a.option_ids
>>> {'option_ids': [3]} # Dictionary object obtained by deserializing the data stored in the databse
...
```

versus

```
for a in SubmittedAnswer.objects.values('option_ids'):
  print a['option_ids']
>>> u'{"option_ids": [3]}' # unicode string as stored in database
...
```